# How to pass props between 2 scene in NavigationExperimental React Native using Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

i am using Naviagtion Experimental and i have a listview, when user select item on listview i will open item detail by using push of Navigation Experimental. I have a issue 
How to pass props between 2 scene in NavigationExperimental React Native using Redux ? (i am using android)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to send props using the `route` object that you already use for navigation.

In your `ListView`

```
const route = {key: 'detail', itemId: 123}
<TouchableHighlight
  onPress={() => handleNavigate({type: 'push', route: route}) >
...
</TouchableHighlight>
```

And in your `NavigationCardStack`'s `renderScene`, you can pass in the props to your detail view component

```
renderScene(props) {
  const {route} = props.scene
  ...
  if (route.key === 'detail') {
    return <DetailViewComponent
      goBack={...}
      itemId={route.itemId} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use react-native-router-flux.

You can get it from here : https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

It's very easy to pass props with that. for example navigating to component X and passing props :

```js
Actions.X({testProps: 'hello', title: 'Page titile'});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can i apply it for pass porps an object that it's got item in the listview and the way is effect to performance in react native ?

Comment: Sure you can pass objects. for example, In my login page, after user logs in, I send an object including all user data ( username email id accesstoken and ....) through props to Terms&Condition page, if user accepts the terms, i will add those data to database. I'm using this solution for a long time now, it's works without any problem. App is online in app store for a while now.